# SQL Server query - combined queries

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know if it's possible to do the below in one query instead of doing a numrows?

```
$select1 = "SELECT service FROM UPSServices WHERE code = '$serviceCode' AND ship_from_code = '$shipFrom'";

$result = mssql_query($select1);

//print_r($result);

if(mssql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    $select2 = "SELECT service FROM UPSServices WHERE code = '$serviceCode' AND ship_from_code IS NULL";
    $result = mssql_query($select2);
}

while ($service = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
    return $service['0'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using SQL Server, so you can do this.  It is slightly more complicated than you might expect.  The following version counts the number of valid values.  If this is greater than 0, then the NULLs are filtered out.

```
select service    
from (SELECT service,
             count(ship_from_code) over () as NumValues
      FROM UPSServices
      WHERE code = '$serviceCode' AND (ship_from_code = '$shipFrom' OR ship_from_code IS NULL) 
    ) t
where (NumValues > 0 and service is not NULL) or (NumValues = 0 and service is NULL)
limit 1
```

Comment: is the `over()` equivalent to `group by`?  In other words, you could get an equivalent query using `count(ship_from_code) as numvalues/group by service`

Comment: @Beth . . . The over is an example of window functions (also called analytic functions in Oracle).  In this case, it does an aggregation to get the count, and then appends the value to each row, instead of bringing them together.

Comment: so the results should be the same, but the performance could be different?  I'm trying to understand the differences between the two approaches.

Comment: @Beth . . . Performance depends on the database.  You would have to look at the execution plans.  For count, you would have to do the aggregation and an additional join, whereas the engine is usually optimized for the window function.  The ranking functions cannot be easily written as aggregations and group bys.

Comment: yes, but you're not using the ranking fnx here.  When you say 'For `count`,' do you mean 'For `group by`?'  I'm not getting why a `group by` approach would require an additional join vs. `over()`

Comment: tried this query but it doesn't bring back any results when I should have a simple service.

Comment: @LeeTee . . . You are right.  I fixed the `where` clause to return both the cases.

Comment: @LeeTee . . . If you only want one row, when there might be several, then use `top 1` in the select clause.  (Your original question appears to be about the logic not the number of rows returned.)  Unfortunately, I am unable to edit the answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need value with NULL shipCode if specified shipCode does not exists

```
SELECT service FROM UPSServices WHERE 
code = '$serviceCode' AND (ship_from_code = '$shipFrom' OR ship_from_code IS NULL) 
ORDER BY ship_from_code"
```

Order by will make sure that if your ship code exists then its at top

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt, this brings out the service for the null value on top even when a ship code exists, which is not what I want

Comment: this is not reliable picking one out based on order by.  I need to select the one with a ship code if its exists, if it doesnt then select one which has a value of NULL.  The order by does not do this.